# プロパティ、印刷、ページ設定で、余白０にすると、印刷が切れる

Tags: 印刷, emeditor

本日、EmEditor  19.8.5をダウンロードして、インストールしたところです。

レシートプリンタ　Epson TM-T70にて印刷しました。
左右上下とも、余白を０にして印刷したところ、上と左が切れてしまい印字されません。
余白を上と左５ｍｍとすれば大丈夫ですが、プレビューの時点で、ずれが確認できるので、おかしいなと思い、報告いたします。

用紙設定は横幅５８ｍｍ、縦２９７ｍｍ
標準のメモ帳では余白を０でも切れません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 一応ここのサイトが[紹介](https://jp.emeditor.com/support/#contact)(`技術的な質問については、Stack Overflow (日本語) または Stack Overflow (英語) に質問することをご検討ください。`)されていますが、**「報告」** であるというのなら、その[お問い合わせ](https://jp.emeditor.com/support/#contact)フォームか [フォーラム](https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/) の方が適切と思われます。また、[EPSON TM-T70](https://www.epson.jp/products/receiptprinter/tmt702/)はPOS端末用途でキャラクタ印刷主体のプリンタです。一応[Windowsデスクトッププリンタのドライバ](https://www.epson.jp/products/receiptprinter/tmt702/feature_3.htm#ANC06)があるとは言え、細かいところまでページプリンタと同等の機能は無いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このサイト、初めて登録したので、よく理解できてなくてすみません。文字だけ印刷するレシートプリンタと文字だけの編集するemeditor、親和性が良いなと、勝手に思っていたところでした。

Comment: Windowsデスクトッププリンタのドライバは普通は印刷データをビットイメージデータで作成するものなので、プリンタの特徴を生かしていないことになります。しかもPOS端末用レシートプリンタは180～203dpiで解像度が低いので2重の意味で生かしていない使い方ですね。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。対応解像度は調べてはいませんが、フォント8ポイントで印刷してます。現状満足してます

Answer (score 1):

EmEditor の作者ですが、印刷の部分のコードを確認したところ、現バージョン (v19.8.5) では、プリンタ印刷時に、指定した余白より、左側に 4.1 mm (0.16 inch)、上側に 4.4 mm (0.173 inch) を引いて、印刷していました。したがって、余白を左: 4.1 mm、上: 4.4 mm と指定すれば、余白は実質 0 となり、問題は無いと思います。

多くのプリンタでは、物理的な余白があり、ページ設定で指定する余白と、実際に印字した時の余白が一致しないため、そのずれを無くすために、このような余白の調節を行っていました。これは、おそらく、ユーザーからのご指摘に対応するためだったと思います。しかし、プリンタによっては、物理的な余白が 0 であり、PDF への印刷でも 0 になるため、今後はこのような余白の調節は行わないようにして様子を見たいと思います。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 余白0で印刷をしたいという、需要のあまりなさそうな問い合わせでしたが、調査していただき、ありがとうございました。